# STL iterator in Qt

Tags: c++, stl, qt4

i want to traverse a list and delete elements greater than 30

```
QList<double> mylist;
QList<double>::iterator myiterator = mylist.begin();

mylist.append(6);
mylist.append(36);

myiterator=mylist.begin();
while(myiterator!=mylist.end())
{
    if(*(myiterator)>30)
    {
        QList<double>::iterator next=myiterator;
        next++;
        mylist.erase(myiterator);
        myiterator=next;

    }
    else
        myiterator++;

    if(myiterator==mylist.end())
        std::cout<<"end of list "<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<" not end of list "<<std::endl;
}
```

output is

```
 not end of list 
 not end of list 
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/maverik/Desktop/Qt/container_class/container_class exited with code 0
```

where as if i make mylist = {36,34} or mylist = {36,9} or mylist={9,10} then output is

```
 not end of list 
end of list
```

the error only comes when the last element is greater than 30 or if greater but the 1st element is also greater than 30

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::remove_if()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the C++ standard containers `erase` returns an iterator to the element after the deleted one, so that part of your loop should be quite simple:

```
 if((*myiterator)>30)
    myiterator = mylist.erase( myiterator );
 else
    myiterator++;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are advancing your iterator twice when you delete an element, here's the fix:

```
QList<double>::iterator next=myiterator;
myiterator++;
mylist.erase(next);
```

That should be done when `*myiterator > 30`

EDIT: actually, QList::erase returns an iterator to the next element. Therefore, this code should do it:

```
myiterator = mylist.erase(myiterator);
```

Comment: I eddited my answer. There seem to be no bugs in that solution.